# simplest way to play mp3 in Discord voice channel

Tags: discord, discord.js

I figured out how to connect my bot to a voice channel, but I have no idea of how to make it play my mp3 files.

```js
bot.on('message', async message => {
  // Voice only works in guilds, if the message does not come from a guild,
  // we ignore it
  if (!message.guild) return;

  if (message.content === '/join') {
    // Only try to join the sender's voice channel if they are in one themselves
    if (message.member.voice.channel) {
      const connection = await message.member.voice.channel.join();
    } else {
      message.reply('You need to join a voice channel first!');
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the [`voiceConnection`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/VoiceConnection) to [`play()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/VoiceConnection?scrollTo=play) the audio file

```js
const channel = message.member.voice.channel;
channel.join().then(async(connection) => {
    const stream = connection.play('/path/to/audio/file.mp3');

    stream.on("finish", () => {
        channel.leave();   // Leaves channel once the mp3 file finishes playing
    });

}).catch((err: any) => console.log(err));
```